# Splitting Timestamp_ntz field into Date and Time in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a field in the format 'timestamp_ntz'.

Example: 2023-12-23 14:00:00.000

I need this to be split into these two formats, both in date (not string) format:

2023-12-23 | 14:00

The end result is getting the Weekday (Mon, Tue...) from the first field and adding a new formula designating AM/PM shift (6:00-14:30 is AM, 14:30-6:00 is PM).

I've tried a few different things such as using To_Date formula, To_Char and then To_Date, and keep getting errors. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So you want two columns, one that shows DOW and the other showing Shift? Why not add that to your question as your desired output?

Comment: Well, I think I can figure the second part out. The bit that's giving me trouble is really just extracting the 'hh-mm' from the timestamp-ntz field. I just wanted to provide context as to why these two fields needed to be in a date format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `time_from_parts` within a `case expression` to set your shift.

```
with my_data as (
 select 1 as id, TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2024-01-16 09:44:34.114') as some_date union all
 select 2 as id, TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2024-01-16 14:24:34.114') union all
 select 3 as id, TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2024-01-16 14:34:34.114') union all
 select 4 as id, TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2024-01-16 04:34:34.114')
  )
select 
 id, 
 some_date, 
 dayname(some_date) as day_name, 
 case when time_from_parts(extract(h, some_date), extract(m, some_date), 0) 
   between '06:00:00' and '14:30:00' then 'AM' else 'PM' 
   end as shift
from my_data
```

| ID | SOME_DATE | DAY_NAME | SHIFT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-16 09:44:34.114 | Tue | AM |
| 2 | 2024-01-16 14:24:34.114 | Tue | AM |
| 3 | 2024-01-16 14:34:34.114 | Tue | PM |
| 4 | 2024-01-16 04:34:34.114 | Tue | PM |

Answer (score 0):

the orignal asked part of the question can be done by casting to DATE and TIME data types:

```
with my_data(ID, some_date) as (
    select * from values
        (1, '2024-01-16 09:44:34.114'::timestamp),
        (2, '2024-01-16 14:24:34.114'::timestamp),
        (3, '2024-01-16 14:34:34.114'::timestamp),
        (4, '2024-01-16 04:34:34.114'::timestamp)
)
select 
    id, 
    some_date, 
    some_date::date as just_date,
    some_date::time as just_time
from my_data
```

| ID | SOME_DATE | JUST_DATE | JUST_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-16 09:44:34.114 | 2024-01-16 | 09:44:34.114 |
| 2 | 2024-01-16 14:24:34.114 | 2024-01-16 | 14:24:34.114 |
| 3 | 2024-01-16 14:34:34.114 | 2024-01-16 | 14:34:34.114 |
| 4 | 2024-01-16 04:34:34.114 | 2024-01-16 | 04:34:34.114 |

But as Isolated's answer shows, the truncated date is not needed to get the day of week. There is possible a simpler way to do the am/pm classification, instead of pulling the time part twice and then using `time_from_parts`, is to just case to `::time`. Also at the same time the CASE can be swapped for a tighter scoped IFF:

```
iff(some_date::time between '06:00:00'::time and '14:30:00'::time, 'AM', 'PM') as shift
```

so

```
with my_data(ID, some_date) as (
    select * from values
        (1, '2024-01-16 09:44:34.114'::timestamp),
        (2, '2024-01-16 14:24:34.114'::timestamp),
        (3, '2024-01-16 14:34:34.114'::timestamp),
        (4, '2024-01-16 04:34:34.114'::timestamp)
)
select 
    id, 
    some_date, 
    dayname(some_date) as day_name,
    iff(some_date::time between '06:00:00'::time and '14:30:00'::time, 'AM', 'PM') as shift
from my_data
order by 1
```

| ID | SOME_DATE | DAY_NAME | SHIFT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-16 09:44:34.114 | Tue | AM |
| 2 | 2024-01-16 14:24:34.114 | Tue | AM |
| 3 | 2024-01-16 14:34:34.114 | Tue | PM |
| 4 | 2024-01-16 04:34:34.114 | Tue | PM |